# How to add two page_url in an event in GA4

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have product and I'd like to track conversions like this:

Step 1. Someone clicks a link then pays
Step 2. After successful purchase the customer is redirected to a thank you page

So both step has to occur for a successful conversion.

I wanted to create a new event in GA4 using the "page_location" -> "Contains" parameter, but I cannot add two "page_location"

So how can I do this in Google analytics 4?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an audience with the sequence you desire and have that audience fire events when it is matched.

You'd want to set the sequence to "within the same session".

Each step would match a page_location (or page_path).

And you'd probably want to set the steps so they are indirectly following each other.

Once you have done that you can add an audience trigger which will fire an event when a user is being added to the audience.

If you want users to fire the event multiple times you could set the audience trigger to 'log additional events when the audience membership refreshes'.

Bonis is you also get an audience of users who have converted.